# Auto Rig Pro 2.8 can't control character

Tags: rigging

So I finally created a character that I liked. Tried to rig it in Auto Rig Pro. But I am not able to get it to work.

Even though I followed all the steps found online. The rig doesnt "bind" to my character and therefore I am not able to put it in a prefered pose.

[image]
Does anyone know what I can do?

Comment: I know you asked this some time ago but I thought I'd chime in, as I don't think many people use Auto Rig Pro. I may need more details, but one thing to consider is that you don't need to use ARP's built in binding methods. The standard Blender ones work also. You can also try using other binding addons. I know that the Voxel Heat Diffuse Skinning addon is compatible with ARP. Granted, it's another paid addon, but I think there's a lite version online somewhere that is free. Failing all else, contact Artell, ARP's author, who answers pretty consistently if you email through the Blender Market.

Comment: Just a side note, but since you were asking about this addon, and since almost no one here seems to use it, I created a chatroom for discussing it. Unfortunately, it's my understanding that you must have at least 20 reputation to join a chat room. :(